# Replace the last Y value in lineSeries

Tags: lightningchart

I want to replace the last X value in line series in a dynamic chart , for example if add different  y values with same X , its plotting the chart multiple times

```
  linechart.add({ x: 100, y: 20 } )
  linechart.add({ x: 100, y: 30 } )
  linechart.add({ x: 100, y: 32 } )
  linechart.add({ x: 100, y: 25 } )
```

But when I run something like above I want the final linechart should be  from 20 to 25 only .I need this for dynamic chart which shows live prices every seconds on last X value , but shifts the x axis only after 1 minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of now the only way to modify the previously pushed data in a Line Series is to clear everything and add the modified data back.

In your case since it is only the very last data point that is changing frequently, you could separate the chart into two LineSeries.
The first LineSeries would hold all the data points that have been, as you described, shifted on the X Axis.
The second LineSeries would hold only two points at any given time, one is the latest "shifted" data point, and the other the most up to date live price. Each time the live price changes, you would clear and then push these two points to this secondary Line Series.

```
linechart.clear().add([ latestShiftedDataPoint, latestLivePriceDataPoint ])
```

This would result in optimal performance, and hopefully also function as you want.

Of course, separating the chart into two series is completely optional, if the total amount of data points is not too high, or if you want to value simplicity over performance, you can of course accomplish the same with just a single LineSeries, again by utilizing clear method each time the live price changes.